# Преобразование указателя в тип и обратно

Tags: golang, указатели

Как преобразовать тип, хранящийся в интерфейсе к его указателю.

Пример:

```
func anyFunc() {
       //... any
   update(model, &model)
       //... any
}


func update(s interface{}, pS interface{}) { 
    // В 100% случаев используется type(s) == type(pS), если не учитывать, что pS -- это указатель
}
```

Так вот мне хочется научиться получать pS внутри функции по s. Как это можно сделать? И можно ли?

Comment: `reflect.TypeOf(s)` не рассматривали?

Comment: Рассматривал. Не ясно, что потом с этим типом делать

Answer (score 0):

Дам намётку, дальше сами додумайте под Ваши задачи. Если всё-равно не поможет, то поэкспериментируйте со звёздочкой. b.(*uint64)

```
func a(b interface{}) {
    c := b.(uint64)
    c = c
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Сергей, вопрос в том, что я не готов работать с типами. Мне важно работать именно с интерфейсами и не переходить к конкретным типам. Поэтому ваш ответ не может быть принят

Answer (score 0):

тут я вижу только один путь.

```
p := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(s))
p.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(s))

myPointer := p.Interface()
```

а вообще я бы передал только указатель в функцию. Просто функция `update` сконструирована не так.

Comment: А как стоит её сконструировать?

Comment: я не могу сказать, что внутри делает функция, но я бы передал просто указатель на модель. если у вас много структур, которые нужно передавать в update, рассмотрите возможноть для каждой определить свою функцию и вызывать ее

Comment: Так в том и вопрос, как обойтись без генерации кода и порождения под каждый тип своей функции.

Comment: расскажите что конкретно нужно сделать